# pandas extract array to columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, apply

How can the array (the length of the array is constant for all elements in the series) be extracted into columns efficiently?

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({'foo':\[1,2,3\], 'bar':\[\[1,1,1\], \[2,2,2\], \[3,3,3\]\]})
d][1]][1]
```

[image]

I.e. extract the array of `[1,1,1]` into a `bar_0, bar_1, bar_3` column?

Is there a better way than manually iterating over the indices in the array and calling `pandas.apply`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]})

d = pd.concat([d, d.pop("bar").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("bar_")], axis=1)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
   foo  bar_0  bar_1  bar_2
0    1      1      1      1
1    2      2      2      2
2    3      3      3      3
```

Comment: Very convenient - but not super fast.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
>>> d.join(pd.DataFrame(d['bar'].to_list(), columns=['bar_1', 'bar_2', 'bar_3']))
   foo        bar  bar_1  bar_2  bar_3
0    1  [1, 1, 1]      1      1      1
1    2  [2, 2, 2]      2      2      2
2    3  [3, 3, 3]      3      3      3
```

You convert the `bar` column to list (nested list), convert it to a dataframe, and join the new dataframe with your initial dataframe.